# Why is my .wav file not playing?

Tags: c#, wpf, input

I want to create an application where i can play a .wav file after the input matches a certain number.
Now I've only come up across threads on how to check if the input is only numbers etc. but i couldn't find any solution yet for my problem.

Here's some code I'm currently using:

```
if(fortwenty_Tb.Text.Equals("420"))
{
    player.Play();
}
```

The application works, but the sound isn't playing.
I've already checked if the `.wav` file was faulty, but it isn't since it does work after i tried playing it with a button controller.

Comment: At what point do you run this code?

Comment: The title of your question does not represent the actual question, which seems to be "Why won't my sound play?".

Comment: Use the debugger to see what value is in Textbox.Text.  Maybe you have some unwanted whitespace.  You might also be passing the criteria but your player might not be setup right.  Provide the code for your player declaration and initialization.

Comment: "The application works, but the sound isn't playing". Is you application *really* working then?

Comment: Are you using MVVM? If you were, you could just check the underlying variable that the Text property is bound to...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to use debugger and breakpoints to ensure that Play() is called. Then you have to check volume of player, volume of your application in windows mixer, and, additionaly, file integrity and codec.